# Screen capturing based on Windows Magnification API fails on Windows 7 64 bit With Aero theme disabled

Tags: visual-c++, screenshot, screen-capture, dwm, magnification-api

I'm trying to capture the desktop screen using Windows Magnification APIs based on code sample given in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607288/Screenshot-using-the-Magnification-library?msg=5570528#xx5570528xx.

The program (32bit executable) works pretty good on Windows8 and Windows10 but fails on Windows7 OS. I compiled the program into 64bit and the behavior is same even for the sample program mentioned in the above [codeproject thread](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607288/Screenshot-using-the-Magnification-library?msg=5570528#xx5570528xx).

After debugging I figured out that the [MagImageScalingCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/magnification/nf-magnification-magsetimagescalingcallback) function returns image width and height as 4*4 instead of my monitor's size and that causes the program to crash or capture a blank screen on Windows7 machines (reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/magnification/ns-magnification-tagmagimageheader).

All the API calls ([MagInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/magnification/nf-magnification-maginitialize), CreateWindow, [MagSetWindowFilterList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/magnification/nf-magnification-magsetwindowfilterlist) & [MagSetWindowSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/magnification/nf-magnification-magsetwindowsource)) are successful. There are no API call failures or mistakes in the code flow in terms of Initializing creating, setting desktop area & assigning filter list.

DWM (Aero theme) is turned off (as per reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/magnification/nf-magnification-magsetimagescalingcallback)

I couldn't find any resources related to this topic even after researching for about 3 days. I have to use Magnification APIs because I have the need to capture windows that stays behind other windows on the desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1:**

I figured out that the application is able to capture the screen only when Aero theme is enabled and that contradicts with the statement in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/magnification/nf-magnification-magsetimagescalingcallback.

I'm not sure how could I make it work on Operating systems with Aero theme disabled or not available by default.

Comment: Win7 is the new XP in many ways.  "need to capture windows that stays behind..." is the killer detail.  That can't work with the DWM disabled.

Comment: @HansPassant you are absolutely right. This should be the answer, thanks.